# Is there a better way to retrieve data from database to an object?

Tags: c#, database, object, datatable

Following is a csharp code which set database data to an object. It set each of the variables needed.

```
objClsProfileMaintenance.Name = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Email = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.ContactNo = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContactNo"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.HPNo = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["HPNo"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Remark = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Remark"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Termination_Dt = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Termination_Dt"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Reason = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Reason"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.PersonInCharge = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PersonInCharge"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Address1 = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address1"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Address2 = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address2"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Address3 = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address3"]);
objClsProfileMaintenance.Address4 = Convert.ToString(dtProfileInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address4"]);
```

I just wondering, is there have any better/easy way to retrieve database data into an object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I just wondering, is there have any better/easy way to retrieve database data into an object?

Yes.

- Reading from a `DbDataReader` (e.g. `SqlDataReader`) directly instead of via a `DataTable` and `DbDataAdapter`.
- Use an ORM:

  - Entity Framework is .NET's first-party ORM.
  - Dapper
  - NHibernate.
  - I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes, even if you used plain ADO.NET. You can use a full featured ORM like Entity Framework or a micro-ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) that just maps the results to objects by name.

Using Dapper, you'd only have to write a single line, eg :

```
var sql=@"Select Name,Email... 
from someTable
where customerId=@customer";

var results=connection.Query<Maintenance>(sql,new{customer=123});
```

Dapper will create and execute a parameterized query using the supplied property names as parameter names, and map the results to object properties by name, taking care of any conversions.

Dapper can also execute queries asynchronously:

```
var results=await connection.QueryAsync<Maintenance>(sql,new{customer=123});
```